# Android Studio - "Android framework is detected in the project"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-framework

I am using Android Studio for development (I/O Preview 0.2.3) and have used AS since I started my current project. Every time I open the project I get the `Frameworks detected: Android framework is detected in the project Configure` message in the event log. I can click `Configure` and it sorts things out straight away but its happens every time I open the project.

Its not really causing any issues, more of an annoyance than anything. Is there anyway of making AS remember that this is an Android project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Android Studio notices a **difference in the path to the android SDK folder on disk and the path mentioned in your *local.properties* file**, it will prompt and upon confirmation update the path in `local.properties`. I think you local.properties file is not retaining the change in SDK path once you close the project. Check you check if something is reverting the changes.

Also, try saving the local.properties file manually after updating the sdk.dir property with correct path..

It looks like this in the `local.properties` file.

```
# change the SDK path below to match the folder on your system
sdk.dir=D\:\\Android\\android-sdk
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to `import project`rather than just opening the project.
**File --> New--> Import Project**

Answer (score 1):

Try open the SDK Manager and check if Android Support Repository is installed. If not, install if and reopen the project.

Comment: I dont think this is the actual solution to this problem

Comment: @TimBoland i have same problem with android studio also have Support Repository is installed but not getting over this problem if you know the proper solution please let me know thank you

Comment: https://github.com/cloudant/sync-android/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#using-intellij-idea--android-studio

Maybe you would need to check your SDK version indicated in gradle build file has been already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Change then name of your project. I had the same problem, because my project had name like "Smile&Smile" and the symbol & crashed normal assembly of my project. Also, don't use symbols like &, !, "",'' in the name of projects.

Answer (score -1):

Just change first row with your build.gradle.
try use

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

[image]