# Frameworks detected: Android framework is detected in the project Configure

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-import

I am using android studio 1.5.1. I have cloned project from git(bitbucket). While importing the project into android studio, getting 2 errors:

1.Frameworks detected: Android framework is detected in the project Configure

2.Unregistered VCS root detected.

Tried these solutions :

[Frameworks detected in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33231460/frameworks-detected-in-android-studio)

[Android Studio - "Android framework is detected in the project"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18430438/android-studio-android-framework-is-detected-in-the-project)

[Android Studio doesnt open project correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29586047/android-studio-doesnt-open-project-correctly)

Above solutions didn't work for me and I am not able to import the project.What can be the cause of it? How can I solve this issue?